# how to integrate phpMyAdmin with Jquery UI?

Tags: phpmyadmin

On my website i want to run phpmyadmin under the menu system displayed on top. I do not want phpmyadmin to take up whole window for itself.

is there a way i can display / run it in a div? so that other elements on page are also visible while phpMyadmin is.

adding image for expressing my question.
[image]

can i kindly get some starting points pls.

ty.

Comment: You could probably try with an `<iframe>`.

Comment: hi Sirko, anyway to show a fiddle plz?

Comment: See the [MDN docu for `iframe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe). There is an example fiddle at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allow using phpMyAdmin inside an iframe, you will need to use the AllowThirdPartyFraming directive. See http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html?highlight=framing#cfg_AllowThirdPartyFraming but there is a warning about a potential security hole.